# Is there a way to add a javascript button that would remove an added graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, web-applications

Dear StackOverflow Users

I am currently working on a data analysis web app.

Now in this app you can drag and drop graphs  and you can remove it by unselecting it. Also you can add the graph with a plus button. Only problem is there is no way to unselect it when you add it by that plus button(Which I put the code of  ""$("#tb_add").button"" )

What I am trying to do is find a way to write a function button that would undo what the add graph button did, or close it or delete it, since there is no unselect button.

My question is: "Is there such a javascript function that would undo or remove what the $("#tb_add").button did.

so let's say I want to add a button called $("#tb_remove").button
is there any simple javascript that would simply undo what was added ?
If there is what is it called ? can you direct me to it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click handler you could add a way to remove the section. jQuery has a .remove() function. You could use classes to control it as well.

```
if($(this).hasClass("added")){
    $(this).removeClass("added");
    $("panel selector").remove();
    $(this).addClass("removed");
} else {
    analysis.addPanel();
    $(this).removeClass("removed");
    $(this).addClass("added");        
}
```

something along those lines should help you.

Comment: i will read about the removeClass function. i was not aware of it. Thank you

Comment: make sure to read about the remove() as well. Also, you could give each panel a new class, or you could append a little clickable x to remove it.

Comment: Here is a snippet of a jsfiddle that has some basics for event handling in this type of situation. http://jsfiddle.net/udwhdr7v/1/

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. You are a genius. Once I get my 15 point reputation I am coming back to vote you up. Thank you bud

Comment: My pleasure. I suggest to everyone to read the jquery non minified script. It really helped me understand javascript. go line by line, and add console.log(whatever is happening here);